# Flutter Web App deployment on Oracle weblogic server

Tags: flutter, dart, deployment, weblogic12c, flutter-web

How can i deploy Flutter web app on Oracle Weblogic server? furthermore is it possible to create war file of Flutter web project?

Answer (score 2):

There's still no official deployment configuration for flutter web to .war file that used for Weblogic deployment format.

Currently, to do that you need to wrap your web build (the result from web folder using `flutter build web`) using Apache Netbeans Web Project tempate.

Step by Step how to do that are explained through this video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txyH0tOEPV0